# My laptop wants me to change my pin because my organization requires it, how is this possible the laptop is private?

Tags: windows-11

As stated in the title I have a private laptop which runs on windows 11.
A few days ago it started asking me to change the pincode because "your organization requires" it.
I do work for two companies as a freelancher, whereby I login to teams. With a work account from either of those two companies.
Usually I login with Windows Hello into my laptop it self, and if it doesn't recognize me I use the pincode I set.

How is it possible, and where can I see this organization?

Comment: If your laptop is truly yours and not the company's, then then you must ask them.  Otherwise go to Users and Groups and ensure you turned off the need to change credentials.

Comment: I work for more than one company, so I would like to find a place where I can see those settings.

Comment: Computer Management, Users and Groups.

Comment: I have opened the computer management, but I can't find "Users and Groups"

Comment: Computer Management, Local, Local Users and Groups.   Then look through the properties of your user.

Comment: All I see is, "System Tools" "Storage" "Services and Applications" when I open these there is none of the options you have described. I have opened Computer Management as an administrator

Comment: Are you using Windows Home?

Comment: Yes I am using windows home

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to upgrade to Windows Pro.  Otherwise you might need to change your PIN

Comment: Hmm yeah that is 130 euros. But thanks for the tip, would they be able to control my laptop? Like see my data, change settings etc?

Comment: Two things:  Windows Pro allows you to control your local settings.  With respect to clients, you should have a one way only VPN to them so they cannot access your machine.

Comment: Hi @John, I bought a key cheaper online and now i'll be updating. Thanks for the help. Do you know what is wrong with my question? I'm new to this forum and new to stack in General and I was wondering what I did wrong.

Comment: I was trying to help and I did not downvote your question.

Comment: Well thanks for your help, it's definitely helpfull to me . But do you have tips for the question, or is it randomly downvoted?

Comment: Questions are not randomly downvoted but as noted I am just trying assist. I understood your question very well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140943/discussion-between-neuquert-and-john).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you with this, two things:

**(1)** You need to be using Windows Pro to do what you wish and change settings.

**(2)** Screen Shot below and once you have changed settings, and OK'd out, you should restart and check.

See in the selection for the User (you) that you can use the Member Tab to see that you are a member of Admin.

You can use the selections for Password Expiry - Mine does not expire.

I think once you set this and all else is well, your PIN should not expire - Mine does not.

I trust this makes sense to you
.

[image: User and Group settings]